# wkhtmltopdf is not rendering images to pdf

Tags: django, wkhtmltopdf

this is my image tag in django templates

```
<img src="{{post.image.url}}" />
```

my url.py

```
path(
            'pdf/<int:pk>/',
            MyPDF.as_view(template_name='templates/post_detail.html',
                          filename='post_pdf.pdf'),
            name='pdf-wk'
        ),
```

this is my view.py

```
class MyPDF(PDFTemplateView):

    template_name = 'templates/post_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, pk):
        context = {'post': Post.objects.get(pk=pk)}
        return context
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boIrJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC7AG.png)

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same issue i installed wkhtmltopdf in my env by using

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

if this doesn't work reinstall wkhtmltopdf
after that check your settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'blog4/media'
```

change this line to this.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

this may work!